# Saving Data from multiple inputs to file

Tags: java, android, file, android-edittext, save

I am developing an android application where the user has to enter text into multiple 'edittext' boxes and then i am trying to take the entered data and save it to a text file. I have got my application to save the data from the first few boxes. I have tried many approaches such as using a for loop and others but it still doesn't work. I'm currently using an array list by adding the first few bits of data to the list, writing it to the text file, clearing the list then adding the rest of the data and trying to append that to the file.
In debugging the application gets as far as adding the first bit of the new data and stops, without crashing or any errors.

This is my code:

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.OutputStreamWriter;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.List;

import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.os.StrictMode;
import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.Toast;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener{

    private Button submitForm,resetForm,btnEmail;
    private String saveName;
    private EditText name,depot,date,time,location,details,outcome,did;
    private String attachedPathFile;
    private File folder;
    File myFile;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        //StrictMode.enableDefaults();
        name = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.nameText);
        depot = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.DepotText);
        date = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.DateText);
        time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LocationText);
        details = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.IncidentText);
        outcome = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.OutcomeText);
        did = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.DetailsText);

        submitForm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.SubmitButton);
        submitForm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @SuppressLint("SimpleDateFormat")
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // write on SD card file data in the text box
                try {
                    folder = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(),"Close Call Reports");
                    folder.mkdirs();
                    saveName = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH mm ss").format(new Date());
                    myFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Close Call Reports/"+saveName+".txt");
                    myFile.createNewFile();
//                  FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile, true);
//                  OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
//                                      
//                  //gets text data to write to file
//                  String data = "Your Name: "+name.getText().toString()+"\n"+"Your Depot: "+depot.getText().toString()+"\n"+"Date: "+
//                  date.getText().toString()+"\n"+"Time: "+time.getText().toString()+"\n";

//                  String data2 ="Location: "+location.getText().toString()+
//                          "\n"+ "Incident: "+details.getText().toString()+"\n"+"Potential Outcome: "+outcome.getText().toString()+"\n"+
//                  "What did you do ? "+did.getText().toString();


                    List<String> data = new ArrayList<String>();
                    data.add("Your Name: "+name.getText().toString());
                    data.add("Your Depot: "+depot.getText().toString());
                    data.add("Date: "+date.getText().toString());
                    data.add("Time: "+time.getText().toString());

                    appendToFile(data);

                    data.clear();

                    Log.v("DEBUGGING", "got here 1");

                    //data = new ArrayList<String>();
                    data.add("Location: "+location.getText().toString());
                    data.add("Incident: "+details.getText().toString());
                    data.add("Potential Outcome: "+outcome.getText().toString());
                    data.add("What did you do ? "+did.getText().toString());

                    Log.v("DEBUGGING", "got here 2");

                    appendToFile(data);

                    Log.v("DEBUGGING", "got here 3");

//                  myOutWriter.append(data);
//                  myOutWriter.close();
//                  fOut.close();
//                  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
//                          "Done writing Comment File",
//                          Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    name.setText("");
                    depot.setText("");
                    date.setText("");
                    time.setText("");
                    location.setText("");
                    details.setText("");
                    outcome.setText("");
                    did.setText("");
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), e.getMessage(),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                // write on SD card file data in the text box

            }// onClick
            }); // btnWriteSDFile

        btnEmail = (Button)findViewById(R.id.Emailbtn);
        btnEmail.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                String[] emailTo = new String[]{"ameyandroidapp@gmail.com"};
                String subject = "Close Call Reporting";
                String [] filePaths= new String[1];
                //if(filePaths[0]==null){
                for(int a=0; a < filePaths.length;a++){
                    attachedPathFile = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().toString()+"/Close Call Reports/"+saveName+".csv";
                            //path+ls+saveName+"("+a+")"+".txt";
                    filePaths[a] = attachedPathFile;
                }
                    sendEmail(emailTo,subject,filePaths);
            //  }else{
                //  Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),"No Files To Email",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                //}
            }   

        });


        resetForm = (Button)findViewById(R.id.ResetButton);
        resetForm.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                name.setText("");
                depot.setText("");
                date.setText("");
                time.setText("");
                location.setText("");
                details.setText("");
                outcome.setText("");
                did.setText("");
            }

        });     
}

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return true;
    }

      public void sendEmail(String[] emailTo, String subject,
                String[] filePaths) {

            Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND_MULTIPLE);
            emailIntent.setData(Uri.parse("mailto: "));
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, emailTo);
            emailIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, subject);
            emailIntent.setType("message/rfc822");

            ArrayList<Uri> uris = new ArrayList<Uri>();
            for(String file: filePaths){
                File fileIn = new File(file);
                Uri u = Uri.fromFile(fileIn);
                uris.add(u);
            }
            //emailIntent.putParcelableArrayListExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM,uris);
            emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, uris);
            startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Email"));  
        }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    }

    public void appendToFile (List<String> SarrayList) {

          BufferedWriter bw = null;
          boolean myappend = true;
          try {
             bw = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(myFile, myappend));
             for(String line: SarrayList ) {
             bw.write(line);
             bw.newLine();
             }
             bw.flush();
          } catch (IOException ioe) {
            ioe.printStackTrace();
          } finally { 
            if (bw != null) try {
            bw.close();
            } catch (IOException ioe2) {
            // ignore it  or write notice
            }
          }

       } 

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm surprised you're not seeing it crash, as it looks to me like you should be getting a `NullPointerException` as you don't seem to be setting the value of `location`. Also, it looks wrong that you're setting the value of `time` using the view with ID R.id.LocationText:

```
time = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.LocationText);
```

but it's difficult to be sure without knowing what you're doing exactly.

Comment: i have spent days looking at this and couldn't see what was wrong. Looks like all i needed was a fresh pair of eyes. I fixed the null pointer exception by getting the value of location and changing time to get the right value and it works. Thanks mate. :)

Comment: Glad to have helped. If you're happy with the solution, please remember to accept it and ideally upvote the answer as well.